# .NET Core Healthchecks UI not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and trying to set up health checks and running into an odd issue and need some help.

When I go to the basic health check URL (https://localhost:5001/hc), I get the following:

```
{
  "status": "Healthy",
  "errors": [
    {
      "key": "AssessmentContext",
      "value": "Healthy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which looks good! However, when I try and go to the UI, it's saying that the application is unhealthy.

[image: UI error]

So it's pulling the endpoint name correctly, but it's not registering it right.

My startup.cs file looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...

    services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddDbContextCheck<AssessmentContext>();

    services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt => {
        opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(30);
        opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60);

        opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint(name: "app", uri: "~/hc");
    }).AddInMemoryStorage();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
        });

        endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI(opt => {
            opt.UseRelativeApiPath = false;
            opt.UseRelativeResourcesPath = false;
            opt.AsideMenuOpened = false;

            opt.UIPath = "/health";
            opt.ApiPath = "/healthAPI";
        });


        ...
    });
}
```

And the csproj file has these version:

```
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage" Version="3.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.System" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.MySql" Version="3.1.1" />
```

```
HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.HealthCheckReportCollector: Error: GetHealthReport threw an exception when trying to get report from ~/hc configured with name app.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.HealthCheckReportCollector.GetHealthReport(HealthCheckConfiguration configuration)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem when the UI tries to call the /hc endpoint. Have you checked the console/network tab for possible front-end failures?

Comment: Can you find out what uri it is _actually_ trying to call?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it looks like it's calling it successfully (I think), but it's saying there's an SSL error.[{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "Unhealthy",
    "onStateFrom": "2020-09-29T14:49:20.863734-04:00",
    "lastExecuted": "2020-09-29T14:51:21.473534-04:00",
    "uri": "~/hc",
    "name": "app",
    "discoveryService": null,
    "entries": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Endpoint",
        "status": "Unhealthy",
        "description": "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.",
        "duration": "00:00:00"
    }],
    "history": []
}]

Comment: You may need to check the console/ouput window on Visual Studio then, there should be logs about that exception

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I updated the question with the exception. Unfortunately, the trace doesn't tell me much, but I'm not too familiar with the health check system.

Comment: For me the problem was I had two IIS bindings, one HTTP that did not work. Which healthchecks tried to use.

Answer (score 10):

I am hopeful that you have already found the solution. But as the question is still unanswered and it was also a problem that I faced I will post how I solved it in the hope of helping others in the future. Thank you.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck("Products", new SqlServerHealthCheck(connectionString))
            .AddSqlServer(connectionString, name: "DataBase");
            
    services.AddHealthChecksUI(setup =>
    {
        setup.UseApiEndpointHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => { return true; }
            };
        });
    }).AddInMemoryStorage();
}        

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/api/hc", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
        endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
        
    });
}
```